# How to explicitly download 64 bit windows 7 update from a 32 bit XP box?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, updates, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offline update of Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows)

I'd like to keep my development box off-net physically as far as possible having connected to the net only at installation. At present I use a dedicated pen-drive to update the antivirus, various SDK updates from my browser box onto the dev-box. The pen-drive is obviously a weak-point ...

The validation tool sees my browser box as Win XP 32 whereas the dev-box is Win 7 64; so there is an obvious incompatibility ... Can I download the various windows update items explicitly for my W 7 64?

Comment: Why do you do this?

Comment: Jacob: Why do I keep the dev box separate? Just paranoid ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download almost all Windows updates manually.  However, it will be challenging finding what you need to download on Microsoft's site and keeping track of what you've downloaded/installed already.  Here are a couple of links that can give you a little guidance.

[WorldStart](http://www.worldstart.com/manually-install-a-windows-update/)

[Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/174290-how-manually-download-updates-but-not-install.html)

You're really creating far more hassle for yourself than is worth your time by following this policy and I really can't see why you would since you apparently have antivirus installed, but of course that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx

Use the Microsoft Download center.  Then sort by Security and/Or Updates. Then on the right, order by most recent date.