# Can I download Windows Update without the 'Automatic Update' feature?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offline update of Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows)

Windows 7 has this amazing update facility for noobs like me.
However the automatic updates become a hassle when you are installing a new HDD and you have to download a ton of other software like Eclipse, Java and so on.
Is there a way through which I can download the updates that have been released till, say today, so when I install a new HDD, I will install these and Windows can then install new ones, if it needs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. Use left menu to filter updates for your OS:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx

You can also try some thing called "microsoft update catalog", but i never used it myself:

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Thanks.aspx?id=140

Comment: I will have to install them one-by-one separately?

Comment: They are .msi packages, so you can just use a .bat file that will msiexec them all in unattended mode (without GUI).

Comment: I am sorry, what? xD I am a beginner at all this stuff so sorry if I ask dumb stuff

Comment: After you downloaded .msi installers for updates, put them into one folder, open command prompt in that folder (shift-right click empty space in folder, "open command prompt here") and execute: `for %s in (*.msi) do msiexec /qb /i %s`

Comment: That catalog site *requires* the internet explorer browser T.T