# Reinstalled Windows 7 - Now cannot connect to any activation server or Microsoft Exchange

Tags: networking, internet-connection, port, exchange, ipv6

I reinstalled Windows 7 this morning, and now I am unable to connect to any activation servers for any Adobe software, and I cannot connect to Office 365 Microsoft Exchange server in Outlook 2013. Networking only works sometimes after initial bootup, and after researching the issue I came across a solution that seemed to fix the issue with Internet not working by disabling and reenabling IPV6 with Microsoft FixIt [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;929852&x=11&y=13).

However, I am still unable to connect to any activation servers or email. I'm thinking this is a port issue, but no router settings were changed. Only the clean Windows 7 install.

Do I need to reinstall Windows, or is there a quick fix for this that anyone is aware of?

**UPDATE**

I have confirmed that when Windows is installed on a **standard SSD**, a Samsung 840 EVO, connected to the motherboard with a SATA cable, this is not an issue. However, when Windows is installed on the (new) hard drive, an OCZ RevoDrive 350 **PCIe SSD**, this is where the problem begins.

I've spoken with OCZ a few times and their line is that the difference in connectivity to the motherboard would have no impact on the networking but I'm thinking otherwise. Maybe it's a bad driver? Something else?

I'm going to try installing a separate network card and use that in place of the on-board LAN. If it works, I'll mention it. But I seriously doubt that this is the solution.

**UPDATE**

Installed Fiddler for a more detailed view of network traffic. Here's what was returned when attempting to connect to the Adobe login server:

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 53 C9 3D F7 86 1C 2F 2F 48 B3 42 58 26 60 1D D6 6E 1E 80 3A 39 6F 76 D5 81 26 60 5A 0D 5E 20 38
SessionID: 6F 6B 2B 1C AF 91 29 EB 85 CE 60 13 9F F4 37 0F F2 98 5B 89 DD 46 60 1F 6D 42 E9 A4 2C 87 13 A6
Extensions: 
    renegotiation_info  00
    server_name ims-na1.adobelogin.com
    status_request  01 00 00 00 00
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
Ciphers: 
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

And when I try to connect using Chrome to ims-na1.adobelogin.com:443

Fiddler says:

```
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

But when I close Fiddler and attempt to reach:

http://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/

I get the response:

```
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

When I connect to:

https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/

I get just a blank page.

This is just REALLY odd. I'm not sure how to interpret a lot of this data, but something is happening when I try to connect with Microsoft Exchange through Outlook, but when I connect to the web app, NO problem. Adobe sign-in servers, same problem. Haven't tried with many other applications, though...

What else can be done to debug & analyze possible causes?

Comment: When you reinstalled, did windows re-verify itself as a genuine copy?

Comment: Yes, not using hacked software. Verified as genuine.

Comment: Reset your router? :)

Comment: Lol. I may have better luck with a wooden bat.

Comment: your date and time settings are correct. right?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Posting an update now with some Fiddler debug info. Not sure what I'm looking at, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. I was using WSUS Offline Updater after reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows) and [this](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/18018-wsus-offline-update-is-a-must) to install Windows updates because every time I tried installing them with the default Windows updater it kept running into the "Failed. Reverting Changes" error after all updates completed.

Apparently, the updater was missing something. I FINALLY got Windows Update to complete without error, and the problem has been solved. I'm not sure WHICH update solved the issue, but it must have been one of them.